# Cannot #include <QWebView> using QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtwebkit, qtgui

I have read a lot trying to figure this out. I am using QtCreator on Ubuntu 13.10.

.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-03-02T09:50:03
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT       += webkit
QT       += webkit webkitwidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = AndroidDecompiler
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

MAIN

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWebKit>
#include <QWebView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();



    QWebView view;
       view.show();
       view.setUrl(QUrl("http://google.com"));
    return a.exec();
}
```

Here is error `':-1: error: cannot find -lsqlite3'`

I think it is due to not being able to include webview. Is their any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install the sqlite3 library as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

Comment: @horvste: because you cannot link against sqlite3 if the library is not installed.

Comment: How did you find out I needed to install this lib? I feel stupid right now.

Comment: @horvste: the error message says so, `:-1: error: cannot find -lsqlite3`. -lfoo means it is trying to link against the libfoo.so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace the header:

```
#include <QtWebKit>
#include <QWebView>
```

with:

```
#include <Qt/QtGui>
```

Comment: Qt/QtGui no such file or directory

Comment: This post does not seem to answer the question. I would personally either remove it or update. Moreover, this answer is totally wrong.